# postgresql now() function returned future date

Tags: php, postgresql, timestamp

Today I found that many of my production databases are having a future date for the column named status_update, which sets ONLY by `now()` function.

Most of the dates are for 8 October:

- 2014-10-08 08:20:42.97564
- 2014-10-08 16:31:30.304743
- etc.

But some of them:

- 2014-10-09 08:31:44.775589
- 2014-10-10 08:50:24.235533
- 2014-10-13 10:42:20.038917
- etc.

Please can anyone help me with this issue? How could it be?

My application is built on PHP. Current time is 2014-10-07 17:35:00.

`SELECT now()` returns `2014-10-07 17:35:56.192627+01`

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

My fault, I missed `pjobdate + current_time` expression that used for setting the value for status_update. Sorry.

Comment: `now()` does not set any column on any table. Please show us your logic (f.ex. your trigger), which updates that column.

Comment: hi @pozs, thanks to you I rechecked all functions and triggers and found this expression `pjobdate + current_time` for setting value for status_update. I surprised as I thought I learned the project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a timezone issue see:
[Local time zone offset in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110216/local-time-zone-offset-in-postgresql)

and try

```
 SELECT  current_setting('TIMEZONE');
```

This is probably true for the 2014-10-08 dates, the ones way off in the future are probably from the date getting set somewhere else.  I would take a look at ALL locations where that column gets updated, triggers, procedures, PHP code, etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All databases have 'Europe/London' timezone as it should be. Yes, I've checked all locations as you adviced. The project is pretty big, probably i've missed something, I'll let you know when find anything.